# Why does a qualitative analysis of this question about refraction differ from the answer found through the application of the equation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, refraction, geometric-optics

Suppose that an object O is in glass ($ \mu $ = 1.5), 6.5 cm from a spherical glass-air interface (from P in Figure 1) where glass is on the concave side and air is on the convex side. In the diagram of this situation in Figure 1, glass lies to the left of the interface while the air lies to the right (of the interface). If O lies on the principal axis and is 6.5 cm from the pole P (mentioned earlier as the spherical glass-air interface) then where will the image of object O be formed?

[image]Figure 1

Based on a qualitative analysis of the situation, I think that the image will be formed on the air side (right side in Figure 1) of the interface.To see why, refer to Figure 2.
[image] Figure 2
As the glass has a higher refractive index than air, when light goes from the glass into the air, it should refract by bending away from the normal. This would mean that the image I of the object O is formed beyond the interface and on the side of the air - the right side.

But, use of the equation $ \frac{\mu_2}{v} - \frac{\mu_1}{u} = \frac{\mu_2 - \mu_1}{R} $ gives an answer of v = - $\frac{130}{17}$ cm $ \approx $ -7.65 cm, which is also the answer my textbook gives; if this were true, then the image of O will be formed in the glass (on the left side). The calculation of v is given below:
$$ \begin{align} \frac{\mu_2}{v} - \frac{\mu_1}{u} &= \frac{\mu_2 - \mu_1}{R} \\ 
\mu_2 = 1.0 \ \ \mu_1 = 1.5 \ \ u = -6.5 cm \ \ R &= -5.0cm \\
\frac{1.0}{v} - \frac{1.5}{-6.5 cm} &= \frac{1.0 - 1.5}{-5.0 cm} \\
\frac{1.0}{v} + \frac{3.0}{13 cm} &= \frac{-0.5}{-5.0 cm} \\
\frac{1.0}{v} + \frac{3.0}{13 cm} &= \frac{1.0}{10 cm} \\
\frac{1.0}{v} &= \frac{1.0}{10 cm} - \frac{3.0}{13 cm} \\
\frac{1.0}{v} &= \frac{13-30}{130 cm} \\
\frac{1.0}{v} &= \frac{-17}{130 cm} \\
\frac{1.0}{v} &= -\frac{17}{130 cm} \\
v &= -\frac{130 cm}{17} \\
v & = -7.65 cm \\
v & \approx -7.6 cm \end{align} $$

Obviously, both of these cannot be correct at the same time, as the image can either be formed on the glass side (left) or the air side (right) of the glass-air interface but not both. So what is the correct answer, and why is the wrong answer wrong?

Comment: HC Verma "Concepts of Physics" chapter 18 exercise 40 b) (adapted) is the source of this question

Comment: The only difference is the sign. Probably the error is due to incorrect application (or interpretation) of the **sign convention**. See note at the bottom of this page : https://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/courses/m309-01a/chu/MirrorsLenses/refraction-curved.htm